# django showing error on form submission

Tags: python, django, forms

I am a beginner to django. I tried implementing many forms on one page. I succeeded in printing the forms the i have got one problem. I just fill form corresponding to button4,i.e., crawl_attri, and click button4, it shows error on other fields that the following field is required. What changes should i make so that it just shows error corresponding to the button i have clicked....

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import *
from selenium import webdriver
import MySQLdb


def my_view(request):
    form = first_form(request.POST or None)
    preset_form = websiteform(request.POST or None)
    crawl_attri=crawl_attribute(request.POST or None)
    crawl_css=crawl_url_attribute_css_sel(request.POST or None)
    prod=prodid(request.POST or None)
    if request.method=="POST":
      if preset_form.is_valid() and 'button2' in request.POST:
        save_it=preset_form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')

      elif 'button1' in request.POST and prod.is_valid():
        save_it=prod.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')

      elif form.is_valid() and 'button3' in request.POST:
         save_it=form.save(commit=False)
         save_it.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('')         

      elif crawl_attri.is_valid() and 'button4' in request.POST:
        save_it=crawl_attri.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')

      elif crawl_css.is_valid() and 'button5' in request.POST:
        save_it=crawl_css.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()    
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')


    return render_to_response('signup.html',{'preset_form': preset_form,'form':form,
            'crawl_attri':crawl_attri,'crawl_css':crawl_css,'prod':prod},RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be instantiating your forms within your if blocks. For example, only pass request.POST to preset_form if button1 is present.